# IIS FTP - new user just access to specific directory of existing site

Tags: iis, ftp

A customer of mine is using IIS FTP server. They have set up several different sites.
On one site there is a directory deep in the structure that a script should write to. I do not want to make the hole site visible to the script, just this one directory. Is this possible?

Comment: Typical blind drop https://winadminnotes.wordpress.com/2015/03/26/blind-drop-or-write-only-windows-2012-ftp-site/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to my own experience:

- First you should have a FTP Site Installed on your IIS.
- Then you create a user (your ftp user) in Local User Manager.
- Next you create a virtual directory as a subdirectory under your FTP Site pointing to the directory you want it to be the root directory for your FTP User. The virtual directory should have the same name as your FTP Username.
- Finally you give Modify or Full permission to FTP User on the created directory for your FTP User.

If you give more details like screenshots and IIS version, or give information of whether you have installed Active Directory or using Local Users,  I can give you more detailed instructions.

Comment: Yes, thank you. It was much easier then I thought. I had read some instructions that made med thought that it was maybe not possible.